# Pandas select row based on value of current row

Tags: python, pandas

let say i have 2 dataframe which restaurant and categories.
Im trying to create a new column that will contains the NUMBER of restaurants that are in the SAME ZONE AND that have AT LEAST ONE CATEGORY in common.

How can i approach this? Here's what I have done so far

```
Restaurant contains: id, zone
      id    Zone   ... 
0     11    H5X    ...
1     12    H2A  
2     13    H5X
3     14    H53
4     15    H21    ... 



Category contains: id, category
      id    category    ...
0     11    Sushi       ...
1     12    Fast Food
2     13    Sandwich
3     13    Sushi
4     14    Noodle
5     14    Fast Food
6     15    Bakeries    ...
```

Now how can i creatd a new columns 'intersection' to originalDF To result to this:

```
     id    Zone   intersection
0     11    H5X    1 (since there is one restaurant, id=13, that is in the same zone(H5X 
                                        and have at least one category in common, Sushi)
1     12    H2A    0
3     13    H5X    1 (since there is one restaurant, id =11, that is in the same zone (h5x) andat 
                       least one category in common , sushi)
5     14    H53    0
6     15    H21    0
```

Can anyone help me please im lost. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd 

# create both datasets
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    'zone': ['H5X', 'H2A', 'H5X', 'H53', 'H21']
})
df1.head()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15],
    'category': ['Sushi', 'Fast food', 'Sandwich', 'Sushi', 'Noodle', 'Fats food', 'Bakeries']
})
df2.head()

# merge datasets based on restaurant id
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['id'])
df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df3.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

```
# count repeating zone / category
cnt = df3.groupby(['zone', 'category']).size().to_frame('count')
cnt.head(10)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

```
# merge counts to first dataframe to achieve desired result
df4 = pd.merge(df1, cnt, how='left', on='zone')
df4['count'] = df4['count'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x <=1 else 1)
df4.rename(columns={'count': 'intersection'}, inplace=True)
df4.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hello thank you very much for giving me this solutions. Im still trying to change some stuff, i think I didnt explain good. 
For X in restaurants, Im trying to find the number of restaurants in the same zone and that share at least 1 category with X. 
Oh as i was writing this, i think ....? all i need to do is count the occurrence. MHmmmm im not sure anymore ill go try more stuff with ur code thanks again !!!!

Comment: your final output, example the row with id = 13, there is 2 row, instead i would like it to be 1 row that show 1 in intersection because there is 1(it could be more) restaurant in the same zone as restaurant id=13 WHERE the restaurant have AT LEAST 1 category in common with restaurant 13.. thanks again

Comment: Expression `df4.loc[df4['intersection'] == 1]` can help you filter dataframe on count of intersections. E.g. `df4.loc[df4['intersection'] == 2]` will leave only rows with 2 intersections.

Comment: Hello again, ive been trying a lot of things since the past weeks. but i still cant seems to get it, ive modified your code and all and i cant get what i want Q_Q. In concluion, for every rows, I want to get the number of restaurant_id that are in the same zone and have at least one category in common with the row restaurant_id. Im still at the first step.. I merged DF1 and DF2 to get DF3. DF1 = restaurant_id, zone, DF2=restaurant_id, category, DF3=restaurant_id, zone, category. Your code give intersection but its not the end result im trying to get. can you please help me :(